# error with authentication in firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to make an app using login with firebase. My app works well on my mobile phone, but I login doesn't work. Since my app has no errors, and doesn't crash, I was trying to figure out the problem in firebase but can't find a problem. Can someone help me?

```
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private Button mBtn;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if(mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, calendario.class));
            }
        }
    };

    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startSignIn();
        }
    });
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

}


private void startSignIn() {

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();



    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Insira email ou senha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Erro com senha ou email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I searched a lot in forums and didn't find anything like it.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?  Have you tried adding an OnFailureListener as well?

Comment: @Submersed _Since my app has no erros, and don't crash_

Comment: @PeterHaddad false -- If there wasn't an error, would he be posting a SO question?  Also, he's not registering a listener for them, so how would he know?

Comment: @Op use this `task.getException().getMessage())` to know what is the problem when loggin in if is there is no error

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the user doesn't exist, so you'd have to create a user if the task isn't successful using `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

also password should be at least 6 characters.

Please Write this inside `if(!task.isSuccessful){`:

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed to sign in: "+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to know why the login is not working.

and remove this:

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Erro com senha ou email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I have added more info to your answer so Tiago(person asking) can solve his problem

Comment: Hi guys, thanks, I wrote "error" because I could not make a post with the word "problem". I tried whith task.getException and this is the message the comes: "An internal error has occured. [Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project (here is 12-digit project number) before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting console.developers.google.com/apis/api/… project number) then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.] I tried to download the .json file again, but it doen't work.

Comment: @Peter Haddad , since my projekt is on Debug mode, it is not yet in the console....

Comment: do as it said in the error, go to that site and enable it

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys. I went to the console API, didn't realize that google created a projekt with APIs till I searched for my projekt (the projekt was like invisible there). I enabled all APIs, and went to toolkit and enabled it too and now my login is working, thanks a lot.